# Tipificação de usuário React + Firebase, Problemas ao consultar o tipo

Tags: react, firebase

Estou criando um sistama que precisa de tipificação de usuario, para isso criei uma tabela no firebase, denominada de users, ao inserir um usuario novo no db o mesmo é setado como 0, usuário convencional, já para ser uma adm o mesmo precisa ter status 1 ou superior. Porem não estou conseguindo consultar o usuario cadastras auth.currentUser.uid, como o id da tabela usuário(os dois são os mesmos) sei que preciso usar a função whare, mas não estou conseguindo de forma alguma. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? É meu primeiro projeto com firebase.

```js
import {db} from "../firebase/config";
import {collection, query, onSnapshot, where, doc, getDoc, getDocs} from "firebase/firestore";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"

export const useCheckTypeUser = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const [typeUser, setTypeUser] = useState(0);
        const loadTypeUser = async () => {
            try {
                const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
                const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                });

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        }

    return {loadTypeUser}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver assim, foi uma boa solução?

```
import {db} from "../firebase/config";
import {doc, getDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getAuth} from "firebase/auth"

export const useCheckTypeUser = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const [dataUser, setDataUser] = useState([]);
    const [adminPermission, setAdminPermission] = useState(null);
    const loadTypeUser = async () => {
        try {
            const ref = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);
            const userDoc = await getDoc(ref);
            setDataUser({id: userDoc.id, ...userDoc.data()});


        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        loadTypeUser();
        if(dataUser.typeUser >= 1){
            setAdminPermission(true);
        }else{
            setAdminPermission(false)
        }
    }, [uid, dataUser.typeUser])
    return {dataUser, adminPermission}
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).